# Sorted and sort function not giving same result

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I have an array nums. I perform following operations:

```
   nums = [1,1,2,2,2,3]

   nums.sort(reverse=True)

   nums2 = sorted(nums, key=nums.count)

   nums.sort(key=nums.count)
```

After performing these operations.I have following values of nums and nums2:

```
nums = [3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1]  
nums2 = [3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

Can anyone tell me why nums and nums2 are not equal?I am confused.

Comment: This question has been answered in this post already. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62818275/how-does-list-sortkey-list-count-works-in-python-3-x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work because `sort` modifies `nums` in place while using it to calculate the counts. It works fine if you use a copy:

```
nums = [1,1,2,2,2,3]
nums_copy = nums.copy()
nums.sort(key=nums_copy.count)
nums
```