# I would like to sort a list by its frequency in ascending order in python. But getting same list as output

Tags: python, sorting

new = [10,15,5,7,10,7,7]

new.sort(key=lambda x: new.count(x))

print(new)

OUTPUT: [10, 15, 5, 7, 10, 7, 7]

desired output:

[15, 5, 10, 10, 7, 7, 7]

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: [This_answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62984639/1740577) of your question.